# Can we extend abelian hyper operations beyond the naturals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Define the ${n+1}^{th}$ hyperoperation to be $F_{n+1}(a,b) = e^{F_n( ln(a), ln(b))}$. The advantage of this is all our operation are commutative now and pretty close to the originals (E.g. Exponentiation is $a^{ln(b)}$). Is there any way to logically extend this definition so the above equality holds for $n \in \mathbb{R}$? Thanks.

Comment: Do the hyperoperations actually yield groups? I don't see that they're either associative or have inverses in general.

Comment: The important thing is if they do, they're abelian. The rest I dont care about. Maybe my tag is a little off.

Comment: I'm curious, do you have a reason to think that this question is going to be easier than the one for standard hyperoperations you asked?

Comment: For a fixed $a, b$, the values $F_n(a,b)$ form a sequence. While there are (usually) many analytic functions $f$ such that $f(n) = F_n(a,b)$ for all $n$, you may be able to chose a specific one with additional regularity requirements. If so, you can use it to extend your operations to a complex domain. I.e., you would not only have $F_{1/2}$ defined, but also $F_i$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: But would they be analytic for differing values of a,b? It would be pretty amazing if that were the case. Maybe I will try a,b = 1 and see how that goes tomorrow. Happy new year!

Comment: +Noah I think it will be easier because its commutative and there is the simple recursive definition. But well have to wait and see while I come up with something. Happy new year!